# Disable html input button from codebehind, after deleting a row

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET webpage that I enter a serial number in, and it then shows up in a gridview below.

I can delete a row(serial#) if I change my mind.  If there is zero rows in my grid I make grid disappear but I also want to make my submit button disappear as well.

How do I do that?  Can I do it from:  `Sub Gridview1_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs)`

If so, I've tried, but I can't seem to find the control to work with it.
Or is there any other way?

HTML example:

```
<div style="width:800px; margin-right: 0px;" id="divMain" runat="server">
    <table stuff...>
        <input id="iSubmit" type="button" value="SubmitHere"/>
    </table>
```

Comment: Make button server side by adding runat="server" doing this you are able to get the button in code behind by its id.

Comment: How are you deleting the rows?

Comment: You can do itusing Jquery/Javascript CSS, make fucntion which count the row. If row  >0 set css button as `display: block;` else `display: none;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code behind you can show or hide the button

```
iSubmit.Visible = False
```

you have to make sure to add the runat="server" attribute

```
<input id="iSubmit" type="button" value="SubmitHere" runat="server" />
```

So, when you delete a row, if the collection is empty then you can hide the button.
When you add a new row, if the button if hidden then you show it.

Comment: Ok, this is so easy its pitiful.  i had all server side controls at first but then i switched the submit button to html so i could disable all buttons so a user can't doubleclick.  walking thru debugging was tricky and i am testing so many various ways & trying to remember which works & what doesn't.  i thought i didn't want server side any more becz some stuff was firing i didn't want to.  but i think this is ok.  Note to self:  when runat=server, it does fire off page load in codebehind, which is ok now since i have some criteria.  i will mark as answered at end of day, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML MarkUp:**

You need to add `runat="server"` to your button so its ID can access from codebehind as the_lotus mentioned above

```
<input id="iSubmit" type="button" value="SubmitHere" runat="server" />
```

**CodeBehind:**

```
 1)   iSubmit.Visible = false; // This will hide the button

 2)   iSubmit.Style.Add("display", "none");// This will hide the button 

 3)   iSubmit.Enabled = false;//It disabled button, user can view but not able to click
```

Comment: This is very late, but sorry, no. The "Enabled" is not a valid property for HTML Input elements.